# REACT-NATIVE Unknown dependency

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` command on my terminal. But I get this error:

> error Unknown dependency. Make sure that the package you are trying to link is already installed in your "node_modules" and present in your "package.json" dependencies. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

My React native versions :

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.61.2

How can I run this command without a problem?

Comment: first install it with `npm install react-native-vector-icons` and then `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

Comment: share your `package.json`

Answer (score 2):

First install react-native-vector-icons , by either `npm i react-native-vector-icons` or `yarn add react-native-vector-icons` if you are using yarn . If you are using React native version >=0.60 then packages are automatically linked , otherwise you can always manually link via 
`react-native link react-native-vector-icons`